# What does the first character of UNIX mode string indicate?

Tags: files, filesystem, file-type

I'm very familiar with linux file permissions, and special perms (sticky bit, suid, guid)

But I don't know what the `c` stands for? Is it a permission, or something else? I've done some googling with and can't figure it out.

Here's the device file that has it.

```
steven@A215:~$ ls -l /dev/null
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Dec 29 20:58 /dev/null
```

[image]

Image Reference: https://detailed.wordpress.com/2017/10/28/understanding-ls-command-output/

Comment: Seems like all of `/dev` has that special permission.

Comment: See http://linuxboxadmin.com/articles/tools-and-utilities/linux-file-permissions-beyond-rwx.html and http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-unix-linux-bsd-device-files/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file

Comment: It's not a permission. It's the file type.

Answer (score 43):

It means that the file is a *character special file* - basically a device file that provides serial access (as opposed to a *block special* device such as a disk drive). For example terminals and serial devices are interfaced through character special files (`/dev/tty1`, `/dev/ttyS0` and so on).

For a brief introduction to device files, see [Linux / UNIX: Device files](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-unix-linux-bsd-device-files/) [cyberciti.biz]. For a more detailed discussion see this stackexchange answer [Understanding /dev and its subdirs and files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18534). To learn about the underlying data structures refer to Chapter 4 of The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide: [Character Device Files](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c577.htm) [tldp.org]

Comment: Good though, but it will be better if you expand your answer little more and provide some useful links. :)

Comment: @SauravKumar please feel free to add some - I couldn't find anything at a suitable level (either added nothing, or dived right into `struct char_device` C code Kernel programming)

Comment: @steeldriver [These](http://askubuntu.com/questions/397493/what-is-the-c-file-permission#comment509214_397493) might give you a start :)

Answer (score 26):

The first character identifies the [Unix File Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types): A character device is marked with a `c` as the first letter of the mode string. Likewise, a block device is marked with a `b`,

```bsh
$ ls -l /dev/null
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Jan 21 21:50 /dev/null
$ ls -l /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jan 21 21:50 /dev/sda
```

there are more of these special devices (files in a sense that everything is a file in Linux),

```
d : directory
s : socket
p : pipe
D : Door
l : symbolic link etc.
```

See this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types) page for more details.

Comment: is there a way to cat that?

Answer (score 7):

`ls -l` outputs a 10 symbol UNIX string of information popularly known as permission string. e.g.

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 userName groupName   13200650 Dec 13 21:23 fileName
```

The first character of **permission string** or **mode string**, known as the *file descriptor*, indicates the file type and the remaining nine taken in groups of three indicate the permissions for the file concerned, where:

- the first group of three characters (after the first character among the 10) indicate owner's permissions,
- the second group of three designate permissions for the group,
- the last group of three designate permissions for others (or the world).

Here, in above example the first character/symbol the ***"-"*** indicates a normal file.

While in the following examples,

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Dec 29 20:58 /dev/null
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 5 Jan 13 20:56 /dev/zero
```

the permission strings' first character is ***"c"*** and like stated above, it is a file-type indicator which indicates a ***character device***.

Apart from the `-`, `c` some other file descriptors are:

- `d` -> directory
- `l` -> symbolic link
- `s` -> Unix socket
- `b` -> block device
- `p` -> pipeline
- `D` -> Door

#### References:

- [Device file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file)
- [Unix Permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions)
- [Modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_%28Unix%29)

Answer (score 3):

The first character in the first column, i.e., 'c ' in crw-rw-rw- above, tells an informed user the type of the file, in this case a character device.