# Meaning of "b" and "c" in file privileges description (output of ls -l)

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory, symbolic-link, ls

Basic question regarding the `ls` utility. What do letters `b` and `c` mean at the beginning of the 10-symbol code describing the items' privileges?

From what I understand, when typing `ls -l`, the terminal provides a list of all items in a directory. Each item description is preceded by a 10-symbol code. This code says what the item type is (first symbol) and what the item privileges for the user, the user group and all other users are.

- If the first symbol is a dash `-`, the item is a file.
- If the first symbol is the letter `d`, the item is a directory.
- If the first symbol is letter `l`, the item is a link / shortcut.

For example:

```
$ ls -l /home/phodor
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 5 phodor phodor 4096 Dec 20 12:02 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 9 phodor phodor 4096 Jan 17 12:02 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 7 phodor phodor 4096 Jan 13 22:42 Downloads
-rw-r--r-- 1 phodor phodor 8980 Jun 27  2015 hello.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 phodor phodor   29 Jan 17 12:02 MyEBook -> /home/phodor/Documents/EBook.pdf
```

However some the 10-symbol code can also start with `b` or `c` for some items:

```
$ ls -l /dev
crw--w---- 1 root tty  4, 0 Jan 17 09:19 tty0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 1, 0 Jan 17 09:19 ram0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jan 17 09:19 sda
```

What do `b` and `c` mean? What is the full list of values that the first symbol of the file description code can take (`-`, `d`, `l`, `b`, `c`, ...)?

Comment: Related: [What does the first character of UNIX mode string indicate?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/397493/what-does-the-first-character-of-unix-mode-string-indicate)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From section [10.1.2 What information is listed](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#index-verbose-ls-format) of the [GNU Coreutils 9.0 manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html):

> The file type is one of the following characters:
>
> ```
> ‘-’
>
>     regular file 
> ‘b’
>
>     block special file 
> ‘c’
>
>     character special file 
> ‘C’
>
>     high performance (“contiguous data”) file 
> ‘d’
>
>     directory 
> ‘D’
>
>     door (Solaris) 
> ‘l’
>
>     symbolic link 
> ‘M’
>
>     off-line (“migrated”) file (Cray DMF) 
> ‘n’
>
>     network special file (HP-UX) 
> ‘p’
>
>     FIFO (named pipe) 
> ‘P’
>
>     port (Solaris) 
> ‘s’
>
>     socket 
> ‘?’
>
>     some other file type
> ```

Comment: where "special file" means it is a device node, as created using mknod().  These are the interfaces to the kernel for various device drivers.