# what is orange colored files in dev directory?

Tags: udev, ls, hal

i looked up in whole root directory 
but i didn't understand one thing
what does orange color in dev directory mean? i know its directory for system devices
but i didn't understand the **c** in ls -l permission section
and what type of file is that? this data file is that used by HAL to read and recognize system devices?
this is the screenshot of terminal
[image: terminal screenshot]

Comment: [What does the first character of UNIX mode string indicate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397493/what-does-the-first-character-of-unix-mode-string-indicate)

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is found on Stack Overflow.

Not just for Ubuntu but for all distros (as far as I understand) that its a character special file. I have linked the source or the information from stack overflow below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23236028/879882

> It's a character-based (as opposed to block-based) device file.
>
> Blocked-based devices are anything where it makes sense to transfer data in (surprisingly enough) blocks. By that, I mean things like disks.
>
> Character-based devices (and again, this should come as no surprise) tend to transfer characters at a time. Things like terminals, serial ports, printers and so on.
>
> If you're running a decent Linux distro, that information (plus more than you could probably ever need) can be obtained with the command:
>
> info ls
>   which contains this little snippet:
>
> ```bsh
> The file type is one of the following characters:
>     -  regular file
>     b  block special file
>     c  character special file
>     C  high performance ("contiguous data") file
>     d  directory
>     D  door (Solaris 2.5 and up)
>     l  symbolic link
>     M  off-line ("migrated") file (Cray DMF)
>     n  network special file (HP-UX)
>     p  FIFO (named pipe)
>     P  port (Solaris 10 and up)
>     s  socket
>     ?  some other file type
> ```

Also if you `man ls` from a command line will bring up the text manual for ls with more details or Google `man ls` for a webpage version.